# Error "The Network Adapter could not establish the connection" while connecting to Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ojdbc

I have Installed Oracle 21c express edition DB. I tried to connect it to my Java application but I am getting "Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection"

ojdbc14.jar file is already loaded.

Oracle DB directory is
C:\app\Usersxyz\product\21c\

Comment: ojdbc14 means it is for Java 1.4, so you're probably using a pretty old version (unless Oracle reused it for a Java 14 version, but I don't think so). In any case, see questions like [IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574414/io-error-the-network-adapter-could-not-establish-the-connection), and [Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22337901/io-exception-the-network-adapter-could-not-establish-the-connection). Without a [mre] we can't help you beyond that.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.    I am using Java 1.8 version. Oracle DB is 21c. For this which version of OJDBC should I use.  Any help can be appreciated.

Comment: See https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-downloads.html (for Java 8, you need the ojdbc8 variant).